# Gnuplot color gradients

Tags: colors, gnuplot, gradient

I need to create a number of vertical gradients in my plot - four in total, in order to clarify direction (N,E,S,W).

```
#set 0 to 45 degrees color
set obj 1 rectangle behind from screen 0.09,0.2 to screen 0.89,0.29
set palette model RGB defined ( 0 "white", 1 "red")  
set cbrange[0:1]
unset colorbox
```

Am I missing something here? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fill a rectangle with a gradient. The `palette` affects only plotted functions or data sets. You can either use the `image` or `pm3d` plotting style to do this.

One example:

```
set samples 100
set isosample 100,100
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "red")
set autoscale cbfix
unset colorbox
unset key

set multiplot layout 2,2   
plot '++' using 1:2:1 with image
plot '++' using 1:2:2 with image
plot '++' using 1:2:(-$1) with image
plot '++' using 1:2:(-$2) with image
unset multiplot
```

The output with the pngcairo terminal and version 4.6.5 is:

[image]

Now you must find a way to integrate this with the other plots you have.

Comment: I am using X11 terminal - does that need any other specifications? I cannot see any colors whatsoever with above code - guess it is to do with the terminal type?

Comment: At the moment I can only test the wxt and windows terminal which both work. I can check the x11 terminal this evening. How did you run the code? Put a `reset` before, or start a new interactive session, maybe you had some residual settings around.

Comment: Ok - I see the colors in an x11 terminal so your code example works..thanks - I just neeed to modify it for my purposes..

Comment: I am having difficulty assimilating the code example into my script.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit? - set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "red")
set autoscale cbfix
unset colorbox
unset key ; plot '++' using 1:2:(-$2) with image

Comment: What does the last line mean? This part : 1:2:(-$2)? I know it is to point gnuplot at the file - file 1, column 2, what is the last signifier for?

Comment: The `++` is a special file name, which internally generates a two-dimensional data set. The number of data points is determined both by `set samples` and `set isosamples` and the `xrange` and `yrange` must be set to fixed values. This generates two columns, which are used as x- and y-values (`using 1:2`). The `image` plotting style requires a third column. In the case you mentioned, the negative value of the second column is used (`(-$2)`).